# Does preg_replace() change my character set?

Tags: php, regex, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have the following piece of code which seems to be changing my character set.

```
     $html = "à";
     echo $html;  // result: à
     $html = preg_replace("/\s/", "", $html);
     echo $html;  // result: ?
```

However, when I use `[\t\n\r\f\v]` as my pattern instead of the special character `\s` it works fine:

```
     $html = "à";
     echo $html;  // result: à
     $html = preg_replace("/[\t\n\r\f\v]/", "", $html);
     echo $html;  // result: à
```

Why is that?

Comment: Both give the same output for me. http://ideone.com/Xo7RLR

Comment: What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: @user4035 PHP version 5.3.24

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have the same problem. It is because of UTF8.

`à` is `0xc3a0` in UTF8. In PHP you can write like this: `"\xc3\xa0"`.

With PCRE the `/s` match `0xa0` like it was ASCII "Non-breaking space".

You can use the [`u` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to resolve the problem.

```
$html = preg_replace("/\s/u", "", $html);
```