# find reason for automatic encoding detection (UTF-8 vs Windows-1252)

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, preg-replace, magento2, windows-1252

I have a CSV with content that is UTF-8 encoded. However, various applications and systems errorneously detect the encoding of the CSV as `Windows-1252`, which breaks all the special characters in the file (e.g. Umlauts).

I can see that Sublime Text (on Windows) for example also automatically detects the wrong `Windows-1252` encoding, when opening the file for the first time, showing garbled text where special characters are supposed to be.

When I choose *Reopen with Encoding* » *UTF-8*, everything will look fine, as expected.

Now, to find the source of the error I thought it might help to figure out, why these applications are not automatically detecting the correct encoding in the first place. May be there is a stray character somewhere with the wrong encoding for example.

The CSV in question is actually an automatically generated product export of a Magento 2 installation. Recently the character encodings broke and I am currently trying to figure out what happened - hence my investigation on why this export is detected as `Windows-1252`.

Is there any reliable way of figuring out why the automatic detection of applications like Sublime Text assume the wrong character encoding?

Comment: Does this happen on Windows?

Comment: The export is generated under a Linux system, I opened the file with Sublime Text under Windows. Sublime Text does not open the file with UTF-8 on MacOS as well. According to https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-does-sublime-detect-file-encodings/16194/5 Sublime Text will try to determine if a file is valid UTF-8 - and if it is not, `Windows-1252`(`cp-1252`?) will be the fallback. And I'd like to know _why_ this particular file fails to be detected as valid UTF-8.

Comment: Although UTF-8 doesn't usually require a BOM, adding one might help these hapless Windows utilities detect the encoding correctly. How exactly to do that with a Magento export is beyond me, but if you can add a manual step in between, just prepend the three bytes before copying the file over.

Comment: Could you check if you didn't mix both encoding somewhere in the file? Try with an other editor.

Comment: Unreliability follows from detection. Just tell the program what you know.

Comment: Maybe you can try the command suggester here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741313/2440340 to double check if your file is actually a valid UTF-8 encoded text file.

Comment: If multiple detectors are failing to detect UTF-8, then the file is obviously NOT encoded in UTF-8, plain and simple.  If it is SUPPOSED to be encoded in UTF-8, then it has an error in it.  The only way to find out is to LOOK AT THE RAW DATA and work out which byte(s) are incorrect.  UTF-8 is a very simple encoding to implement by hand. It would also help if you know what the original text is so you can know what the UTF-8 encoded form is supposed to look like, and then compare that to your file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, the file had mixed contents. The question was how to find out which characters were not UTF-8 encodet, because the majority is and it wasn't easy to immediately identify the characters with wrong encoding. I'll be posting an answer how I then found out what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in the end to find out why the file was not detected as UTF-8, i.e. to find the characters that were not encoded in UTF-8. Since PHP is more readily available to me, I decided to simply use the following script, to force convert anything that is not UTF-8 to UTF-8, using the very handy [neitanod/forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) library.

```php
$before = file_get_contents('export.csv');
$after = \ForceUTF8\Encoding::toUTF8($before);
file_put_contents('export.fixed.csv', $after);
```

Then I used a file comparison tool like Beyond Compare to compare the two resulting CSVs, in order to see more easily which characters were not originally encoded in UTF-8.

This in turn showed me that only one particular column of the export was affected. Upon further investigation I found out that the contents of that column were processed in PHP with the following `preg_replace`:

```php
$value = preg_replace('/([^\pL0-9 -])+/', '', $value);
```

Using `\p` in the regular expression had an unknown side effect: all the special characters were converted to another encoding. A quick solution to this is to use the `u` flag on the regex (see [regex pattern modifiers reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)). This forces the resulting encoding of this `preg_replace` to be UTF-8. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630158/374996).