# PHP unexpected output when replacing character code 8217 in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm running into an unexpected character replacement problem. The character code is 8217, `’`.

I've tried escaping the character with a slash, but it didn't make a difference.

```
php > $a = preg_replace('/([.,\'"’:?!])<\/a>/', '</a>\1', 'letter">Evolution’</a> </li>');
php > echo($a);
// => letter">Evolution/a> </li>

// Just to show that it works if the character is different
php > $a = preg_replace('/([.,\'"’:?!])<\/a>/', '</a>\1', 'letter">Evolution"</a> </li>');
php > echo($a);
letter">Evolution</a>" </li>
```

I would expect it to output

`letter">Evolution</a>’ </li>`

instead of

`letter">Evolution/a> </li>`

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629893/does-preg-replace-change-my-character-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, pcre (the php regex engine) considers your pattern as a succession of single byte encoded characters. So when you write `[’]` you obtain a character class with the three bytes on which THE RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019) is encoded, i.e.: `\xE2`, `\x80`, `\x99`.

In other words, writting `"/[’]/"` in this default mode is like writting `"/[\xE2\x80\x99]/"` or `"/[\x80\xE2\x99]/"` or `"/[\x99\xE2\x80]/"` etc., the regex engine doesn't see a sequence of bytes that represents the character `’` but only three bytes.

This is the reason why you obtain a strange result, because `[.,\'"’:?!]` will only match the last byte of `’` so `\x99`.

To solve the problem, you have to force the regex engine to read your pattern as an UTF-8 encoded string. You can do that with one of this ways:

- `preg_replace('~(*UTF)([.,\'"’:?!])</a>~', '</a>\1', 'letter">Evolution’</a> </li>');`
- `preg_replace('~([.,\'"’:?!])</a>~u', '</a>\1', 'letter">Evolution’</a> </li>');`

This time the three bytes `\xE2\x80\x99` are seen as an atomic sequence for the character `’`.

Notice: `(*UTF)` is only for the reading of the pattern but the `u` modifier does more things: it extends shorthand character classes (like `\s`, `\w`,`\d`) to unicode characters and checks if the subject string is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: > n other words, writting "/[’]/" in this default mode is like writting "/[\xE2\x80\x99]/" or "/[\x80\xE2\x99]/" or "/[\x99\xE2\x80]/" etc., the regex engine doesn't see a sequence of bytes that represents the character ’ but only three bytes.

> This is the reason why you obtain a strange result, because [.,\'"’:?!] will only match the last byte of ’ so \x99.

Ahh, awesome, really appreciate the explanation of why it was failing :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add unicode flag to the regex:

```
$a = preg_replace('/([.,\'"’:?!])<\/a>/u', '</a>\1', 'letter">Evolution’</a> </li>');
#                              here ___^
echo($a);
```